# Postgresql query to get sum of tree

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi guys I would like to ask about postgresql and what could be the best query to get sum of column when you have table of elements that has some descendants of more levels ie.

<kbd>id</kbd>      <kbd>id_parent</kbd><kbd>value</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>null</kbd>          <kbd>3</kbd>       
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>null</kbd>          <kbd>4</kbd>       
<kbd>3</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>2</kbd>       
<kbd>4</kbd>      <kbd>2</kbd>             <kbd>3</kbd>       
<kbd>5</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>              <kbd>4</kbd>      
<kbd>6</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>              <kbd>2</kbd>      

<kbd>7</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>              <kbd>5</kbd>      
<kbd>8</kbd>      <kbd>4</kbd>              <kbd>7</kbd>

so the result would be rows with sum of all of their tree as follows

value of ids 5 and 6 together is 6 plus value of their parent would be 8 plus his parent would be 11, and same for items with id 7 and 8 so the grandˇparent with id=2 would have value 19

<kbd>id</kbd>      <kbd>id_parent</kbd><kbd>value</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>null</kbd>          <kbd>11</kbd>     
<kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>null</kbd>          <kbd>19</kbd>

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursive CTEs:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select t.id, t.value, ultimate_parent as id
      from t
      where id_parent is null
      union all
      select t.id, t.value, cte.ultimate_parent
      from cte join
           t
           on t.id_parent = cte.id
    )
select ultimate_parent, sum(value)
from cte
group by ultimate_parent;
```

The recursive part starts with the ultimate parents -- the records whose parent is `NULL`.  It then brings in lower levels, step-by-step, keeping the id of the ultimate parent.

The final aggregation just sums the values together.

Comment: great, I knew that somehow I should use cte but I am quite new to postgre so this helps a lot thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

There is a small correction to be applied in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41070015/17726418).

If we directly run the query, it will result in:

> ERROR: pq: column "ultimate_parent" does not exist

The issue is in the first select clause:

```sql
select t.id, t.value, ultimate_parent as id
```

It should be replaced with:

```sql
select t.id, t.value, id as ultimate_parent
```

So the correct query should be:

```sql
with recursive cte as (
      select t.id, t.value, id as ultimate_parent
      from t
      where id_parent is null
      union all
      select t.id, t.value, cte.ultimate_parent
      from cte join
           t
           on t.id_parent = cte.id
    )
select ultimate_parent, sum(value)
from cte
group by ultimate_parent;
```